# how do I return a value from a script that I am sending to Mongo?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a set of database administration tasks that need to run after some other rake tasks. So I read the [Ruby Mongo driver source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/db.rb) and a few blog posts and I ended up with this code:

```
scr = open("./scripts/update_stats.js", &:read)
db = Mongoid::Config::master
result = db.command({:$eval => scr})
logger.debug result
logger.warn "Finished updating stats"
```

In the script I have several functions and then one final one:

```
r = update_stats();
print("update result:");
print (r);
```

Ok, so it's all running fine when I run it directly via the command line. Well, it seems to be. But I'd like to take the result value and stow it into my logs. I could store the value into the database and then pull it out I suppose. Seems like there should be a better way. What I do get it my logs is:

```
DEBUG 2012-01-03 22:27:03 -0800 (21392) {"retval"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}
```

That doesn't tell me much other than that it didn't blow up. So, how can I get the returned value of `update_stats` and log it in my Ruby code?

Comment: how's your update_stats.js look like?

Comment: @Nat its about 130 lines that iterates a set of records, does some calculations and then updates the records; it's a bit too big to include in my OP. Something specific you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there are two potential issues here.

The first issue is that you are running a JS file against the database, but I'm not really clear how this works. It looks like some special feature of Mongoid? What result are you expecting?

The second issue is that it's not clear why you're using a JS file at all if the rake machine has driver access. What commands are you running that cannot be simply run as commands via the Ruby driver directly?

In general, the only time you need to bring in an arbitrary JS file is when you're calling jobs directly via the `mongo` program. So you would run `mongo my_map_reduce.js` from a `cron` job and this would make sense.

If the commands you're running are accessible via the driver (*this is true 99% of the time*). Then just write the whole admin script in Ruby.

Comment: Agreed, you should write the entire thing in ruby. You should be able to do pretty much everything using the ruby driver.

Comment: You guys are missing one thing: Mongodb runs js natively. So for things that are only happening in the database like this, js is probably going to have better performance. I don't have any proof of that, but it does make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: The problem here is that MongoDB does *not* run JS natively. In fact it uses a JS VM to run certain commands like Map/Reduce. This has proven so ineffective that 10gen has developed a new aggregation framework (that is native) and they're working to switch out the JS engine to allow for multi-threading. However, in your case, you're just running a series of commands from a file using the shell (*a JS driver*), so you're not getting any performance benefits here.

Comment: I built the same set of calculate/updates in JS and Ruby. The JS version was 25% faster. However I decided that the Ruby version was easier to maintain and understand -- worth the difference in performance since we're talking about a few seconds on a daily basis.